# Positive right derivative property

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f:I=[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f^{+}(0)>0$, and $f(0)\geq 0$ where $f^{+}$ denotes right derivative. Then does it follow that for non-negative values $t$ near $0$ one has $f(t)\geq 0$?

Isn't this justby continuity of $f$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $f(t) \ge f(0)$? That would make more sense.

Comment: @MartinR I forgot to say $f(0)\geq 0$

Comment: Now write down the definition of $f^+(0)$ as a limit, your conclusion follows easily.

Comment: @MartinR that's what i'm saying. It should be easy I just want to mke sure im not overthinking

Comment: It is not “just by continuity of $f$” ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to do with right derivative on its own but rather because you don't control $f(0)$.

Take for ex $f : x \mapsto  x - 1 $

If $f(0) \geq 0$ then your claim is true. Try to write the $\varepsilon$ definition of $f^+(0)$ and try to show what you need to.

It can also be nice to obtain a counterexample where $f$ is always non positive in any neighborhood when for ex $f^+(0) =0$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that $f(0)\geq 0$.